# "Block if without end if" or "for without next"

Tags: vba, excel

I can't make the error go away, it only turns into a different error. The IF at the top is ended. The FORs all align. If I add an 'End IF' before "End Sub", I get the error "for without next". 
Here is my code:

```
 Sub Updatevalue()

    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim wb2 As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim ws3 As Worksheet
    Dim ws4 As Worksheet

    wbname1 = Range("IllustWBDir1")

    Set wb1 = Application.Workbooks.Open(wbname1)

    ThisWorkbook.Activate

    For Item = 0 To Sheets("Documentation").ListBox1.ListCount - 1

      If Sheets("Documentation").ListBox1.Selected(Item) = True Then

          If Sheets("Documentation").ListBox1.List(Item) = "Compact" Then
             Range("Statename") = "MA"
             stname = "C"
          Else
             Range("Statename") = Sheets("Documentation").ListBox1.List(Item)
             stname = Range("Statename")
          End If

          Range("Statename").Copy
          wb1.Activate
          Sheets("Inputs").Select
          Range("State").Select
              Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
              :=False, Transpose:=False
          Application.Calculate

          Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("PPGs")
          Set tb1 = ws1.Range("PPG_Table")

          ThisWorkbook.Activate


    Base_Schematic = ThisWorkbook.Names("Base_Schematic").RefersToRange


' Key Ages
Dim ages(1 To 8) As String
    ages(1) = "30"
    ages(2) = "40"
    ages(3) = "50"
    ages(4) = "55"
    ages(5) = "60"
    ages(6) = "65"
    ages(7) = "70"
    ages(8) = "75"

' Gender
Dim uniorgd(1 To 3) As String
    uniorgd(1) = "U"
    uniorgd(2) = "F"
    uniorgd(3) = "M"

' Bps
Dim Bps(1 To 6) As String
    Bps(1) = "1"
    Bps(2) = "2"
    Bps(3) = "3"
    Bps(4) = "4"
    Bps(5) = "5"
    Bps(6) = "6"

' UW Classes
Dim UWs(1 To 4) As String
    UWs(1) = "P"
    UWs(2) = "S"
    UWs(4) = "1"
    UWs(5) = "2"

' Marital Status
Dim Mar(1 To 2) As String
    Mar(1) = "S"
    Mar(2) = "M"

' Inflations
Dim Infls(1 To 2) As String
    Infls(1) = "3C_PPG"
    Infls(2) = "5C_PPG"


For a = 1 To 8
  For b = 1 To 3
    For c = 1 To 6
      For d = 1 To 4
        For e = 1 To 2
          For f = 1 To 2

            findval = ages(a) & uniorgd(b) & Bps(c) & UWs(d) & Mar(e) & Infls(f)
            wb1.Activate
            Sheets("PPGs").Select
            pasteval = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Right(findval, 10), Range("PPG_Table"), Range("2,84"), False)

          Next f
        Next e
      Next d
    Next c
  Next b
Next a


End Sub
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You seem to be missing **Next** for the first **For** and **End If** for the First **If**

since you understand the logic, you should be able to place them appropriately.

```
Sub Updatevalue()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim wb2 As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim ws3 As Worksheet
    Dim ws4 As Worksheet

    wbname1 = Range("IllustWBDir1")

    Set wb1 = Application.Workbooks.Open(wbname1)

    ThisWorkbook.Activate

    For Item = 0 To Sheets("Documentation").ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        If Sheets("Documentation").ListBox1.Selected(Item) = True Then
            If Sheets("Documentation").ListBox1.List(Item) = "Compact" Then
                Range("Statename") = "MA"
                stname = "C"
            Else
                Range("Statename") = Sheets("Documentation").ListBox1.List(Item)
                stname = Range("Statename")
            End If

            Range("Statename").Copy
            wb1.Activate
            Sheets("Inputs").Select
            Range("State").Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                                        :=False, Transpose:=False
            Application.Calculate

            Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("PPGs")
            Set tb1 = ws1.Range("PPG_Table")

            ThisWorkbook.Activate

            Base_Schematic = ThisWorkbook.Names("Base_Schematic").RefersToRange

            ' Key Ages
            Dim ages(1 To 8) As String
            ages(1) = "30"
            ages(2) = "40"
            ages(3) = "50"
            ages(4) = "55"
            ages(5) = "60"
            ages(6) = "65"
            ages(7) = "70"
            ages(8) = "75"

            ' Gender
            Dim uniorgd(1 To 3) As String
            uniorgd(1) = "U"
            uniorgd(2) = "F"
            uniorgd(3) = "M"

            ' Bps
            Dim Bps(1 To 6) As String
            Bps(1) = "1"
            Bps(2) = "2"
            Bps(3) = "3"
            Bps(4) = "4"
            Bps(5) = "5"
            Bps(6) = "6"

            ' UW Classes
            Dim UWs(1 To 4) As String
            UWs(1) = "P"
            UWs(2) = "S"
            UWs(4) = "1"
            UWs(5) = "2"

            ' Marital Status
            Dim Mar(1 To 2) As String
            Mar(1) = "S"
            Mar(2) = "M"

            ' Inflations
            Dim Infls(1 To 2) As String
            Infls(1) = "3C_PPG"
            Infls(2) = "5C_PPG"


            For a = 1 To 8
                For b = 1 To 3
                    For c = 1 To 6
                        For d = 1 To 4
                            For e = 1 To 2
                                For f = 1 To 2
                                    findval = ages(a) & uniorgd(b) & Bps(c) & UWs(d) & Mar(e) & Infls(f)
                                    wb1.Activate
                                    Sheets("PPGs").Select
                                    pasteval = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Right(findval, 10), Range("PPG_Table"), Range("2,84"), False)
                                Next f
                            Next e
                        Next d
                    Next c
                Next b
            Next a
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

This is one of the good reason to properly indent your code !

Answer (score 3):

The first *For* and the first *If* have no *Next* and *End If*.

One way to avoid this kind of problems is to write the end statement right after you write the conditions statement, and then you move inside the cicle and write the code.